# Mongoose : make request where condition is an array

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I'm trying to make a request with Mongoose from a Node.js server. In the collection the documents have a property like this :

```
industryIdentifiers:[{
  type: { type: String, required: false },
  identifier: { type: String, required: false }
}],
```

My intention is to query document which has that same property. I tried like this :

```
`Book.find({industryIdentifiers: book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers},(err, findedBook) => { //some process here })`
```

where book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers is formatted like this :

`[{"type":"ISBN_13","identifier":"9781781103524"},{"type":"ISBN_10","identifier":"1781103526"}]`

This is not working, but I have no clue on how to perform that kind of request with Mongoose.

I would really appreciated help on this one. Thank you.

Comment: Could you please post a sample document?

Comment: @dnickless Oups, I haven't pay attention to your comment. Here is a sample : `{"_id":"5a8dd9adf30ad90878de428e","industryIdentifiers":[{"_id":"5a8dd9adf30ad90878de4290","type":"ISBN_13","identifier":"9781576906385"},{"_id":"5a8dd9adf30ad90878de428f","type":"ISBN_10","identifier":"1576906388"}]}`

Comment: If you could get rid of the `_id` field inside you subdocuments then your approach would work... If you cannot do that you'll need to resort to the aggregation framework if you want to do everything on the database side.

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this

```
   var book = {};
   book['data'] = [];

   for(i in book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers){

        Book.find({industryIdentifiers: $elemMatch : 
                  {type   :  book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[i].type ,
                  identifier : book.volumeInfo.industryIdentifiers[i].identifier}

                   },(err, findedBook) => {

                          book['data'].push({
                              result : findedBook
                          });
            });
   }

     //Now your find ouptut is in book.data
     You can perform your action here  with book.data
        //some process here
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'll try this solution later today and 'll keep in touch about it :-)